# NSImageView disappears without reason

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsimageview

I let my window autoresize to the visible screen. There is no problem in that code.

But the problem lies here I need to add ImageViews to the window and of course they should also be able to resize.

Code to create the ImageViews and to make window fit to current visible

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    int x,y;
    NSInteger rowCounter,gapX,gapY;
    rowNumber=5;
    rowCounter=0;
    gapX=0;
    gapY=0;
    personNumber=10;
    startX=20;
    startY=20;
    NSRect rect;
    NSSize size;
    NSScreen *scren=[NSScreen mainScreen];
    rect=scren.visibleFrame;
    y=rect.size.height;
    x=rect.size.width;
    NSLog(@"%s%s%d%s%d","screen"," y size=",y," x size=",x);
    y=window.frame.size.height;
    x=window.frame.size.width;
    NSLog(@"%s%s%d%s%d"," window"," y size=",y," x size=",x);
    timer1 =[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(resizeWindow1) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    rahmen=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:25];
    NSPoint p;
    y=rect.size.height;
    x=rect.size.width;
    size.height=y;
    size.width=x;
    p.x= rect.origin.x;
    p.y= rect.origin.y+y;
    [window setContentSize:size];
    [window setFrameTopLeftPoint:p];
    width =x-(20*(personNumber/2));
    width=(width/(personNumber/2))-(20/(personNumber/2));
    NSLog(@"%s%ld","\n width: ",(long)width);

    high= y-(20*rowNumber);
    high=high/rowNumber-(20/rowNumber);
    NSLog(@"%s%ld","\n high: ",(long)high);
    for (indexRahmen=0; indexRahmen<25; ) {

        if (indexRahmen>0 && indexRahmen%(personNumber/2)==0) {
            rowCounter=rowCounter+1;
            gapX=0;
            gapY=gapY+1;
        }
        else if (indexRahmen%(personNumber/2)!=0){
            gapX=gapX+1;
        }
        if (rowCounter==rowNumber) {
            rowCounterr=rowNumber-1;
            gapY=gapY-1;
        }

        rect=NSMakeRect(startX+(width*(indexRahmen%(personNumber/2)))+(gapX*20),(startY+(rowCounter*high)+(gapY*20)),width, high);

        NSImageView *imageView=[[NSImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
        imageView.image = [NSImage imageNamed:@"umrandung.png"];
        [rahmen insertObject:imageView atIndex:indexRahmen];
        [window1view.self addSubview:imageView];
        NSLog(@"%s%ld","\n IndexZahl: ",(long)indexRahmen);
        indexRahmen=indexRahmen+1;
    }

}
```

the resizing action called by timer1 is nearly the same except that:

```
NSImageView *imageView= [rahmen objectAtIndex:indexRahmen];
    imageView.frame= rect;
    imageView.image = [NSImage imageNamed:@"umrandung.png"];
    [rahmen insertObject:imageView atIndex:indexRahmen];
```

and that imageView is not added to subview of window1view

and the strange thing that does happen is that the 1. NSImageView disappears but when I check the coordinates they are on the correct spot so I don't know why it disappears.

Comment: There's a reason why we use English everywhere (even in variable names) ;) If they are meaningful they tell other developers a lot about what you wanna do/mean. *I* understand what you mean but there are millions of other developers out there who don't have any clue about what you think you do in your code ;)

Comment: i changed now the varible names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out myself how to fix it.

I used instead of creating the ImageView with:

```
[rahmen objectAtIndex:indexRahmen];
```

I used:

```
for (NSImageView* ImageView in rahmen)
```

and It works fine with that.

Sadly I don't know the reason why it disappeared with the other method